# Find if $f_n\left(x\right)$ uniformly continuous at any closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be Continuously Differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$

Define $f_n\left(x\right)=n\left[f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(x\right)\right]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Find $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(f_n\left(x\right)\right)$

And prove that at any closed interval of the form $[a,b]$
the functions sequence $\left(f_n\left(x\right)\right)$ is uniformly continuous.

My solution until now :

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(f_n\left(x\right)\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)=\left[h=\frac{1}{n}\right]=\lim \:_{h\to \:0\:}\left(\frac{\left(f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)}{h}\right)=f'\left(x\right)$$

How can I show that $(f_n(x))$ is uniformly continuous at any interval of the form $[a,b]$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Derivative is Bounded $\Rightarrow$ uniformly contnuous.

Use Mean Value Theorem, such an $f$ is Lipschitz, which is much stronger.

Comment: I understand. But how to assume that the derivative is bounded ?

Comment: @idandi, Continuous functions on closed intervals are bounded. See Bolzano's Theorem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: yes I saw. Thanks